# Summing values of field in polyline layer that intersects grid in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, overlapping-features, summarizing

In QGIS I have created a grid. Now I want this grid to be intersected with a line shape. The line shape contains numbers in field `"x"`. I want to know the sum of field `"x"` in each grid cell.

How can I achieve that in QGIS?

Comment: The process is much the same as your previous Question, but GIS SE isn't a tutorial site, so we're looking for *focused* questions that detail what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: thanks a lot. that helps tremendously! I am stuck at the point that I don't know how to count lines in polygons as I can not find an equivalent function to "count points in polygons".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ["Join attributes by location (summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary) tool with:

'Input' : *name_of_grid_layer*
'Join layer' : *name_of_polyline_layer*
'Geometric predicate' : *intersects*
'Fields to summarize (leave empty to use all fields)' : *x*
'Summaries to calculate (leave empty to use all fields)' : *sum*.